# Search a text in multiple column using CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate

I need to search a text if exist using criteria builder.
If this text exist in any one column, I need to retrieve the data.

Sample Data:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Event> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Event.class);
Root<Event> root = criteriaQuery.from(Event.class);
ArrayList<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventId), searchText));

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventModule), searchText));

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventName), searchText));
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(builder.or(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[conditions.size()])));
javax.persistence.Query query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Event> eventList = query.getResultList();
return eventList;
```

Right now I am using `OR clause` to check the data existence of data.
Can I know how can I change this query using where **IN clause.**

Answer (score 0):

You don't need your `OR` condition:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Event> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Event.class);
Root<Event> root = criteriaQuery.from(Event.class);

ArrayList<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<>();

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventId), searchText));

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventModule), searchText));

conditions.add(builder.equal(root.get(Event_.eventName), searchText));

//CHANGE THIS ROW
criteriaQuery.select(root).where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[conditions.size()])));

javax.persistence.Query query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<Event> eventList = query.getResultList();
return eventList;
```

Comment: I need the list even the text exist in any one column. I need the OR clause to do it right??